# .IsBodyHtml=true causes an empty email body to be sent, but .IsBodyHtml=false sends the body content

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exchange-server, mailmessage

I have a WCF service that sends email based on user input. It was brought to my attention that,  recently, a particular user's email were being delivered without any body text. If .IsBodyHtml is set to true, no body text is transferred; but, if .IsBodyHtml is set to false, the body has the appropriate text. 
However, it doesn't seem to be consistent, as it seems to occur only when said user's email address is set as the "From" address.
Tech Details:
We have an MS Exchange mail server. I'm composing a MailMessage object passing it to the built-in SMTP class to send the message.

The code has been simplified, a bit, for brevity/clarity. Nevertheless, the original code is pretty standard/straight-forward. `email` refers to a LINQ-to-SQL class object

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(email.fromAddress);
message.To.Add(email.toRecipient);
message.Subject = email.emailSubject;

//set email body
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = email.emailBody;

Attachment attachmentFile = null;
if (email.hasAttachment == true)
{
    //retrieve attachments for emailID
    var attachments = from attach in db.EmailAttachments
                      where attach.emailID == emailID
                      select attach;

    foreach (var attachment in attachments)
    {//attach each attachment
        string filePath = Path.Combine(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, emailID.ToString(), attachment.fileName);
        attachmentFile = new Attachment(filePath);
        message.Attachments.Add(attachmentFile); //set attachment from input path
    }
}

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT); //set SMTP server name/URL and port
client.Send(message); //try to send the SMTP email
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem relates to a user, it is probably related to the setting of this user.

Log in as that user and open outlook

Select: File -> Options -> Mail

Scroll down to the section "Message Format"

Probably "Convert to PlainText Format is selected" change this to "Convert to HTML Format"

Comment: Thanks for the response/tip, but, that setting should only affect email sent by the user in Outlook, not email sent by my service code (using our SMTP server). Apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: It may be that the setting is saved in the user profile on the server, and therefore affects mail sent by that user account. Check the setting for that user and compare with a user for who it works.